# Trying to rename files by iterating over a dictionary with their names

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, file-rename

```
import os

os.chdir('/Users/julianl/Desktop/Rick and Morty Season 1')
names = {'1' : 'Pilot', '2' : 'Lawnmower Dog',  '3' : 'Anatomy Park',  '4' : 'M. Night Shaym-Aliens!',  '5' : 'Meeseeks and Destroy', '6' : "Rick Potion #9", '7' : "Raising Gazorpazorp", '8' : "Rixty Minutes", '9' : "Something Ricked This Way Comes", '10' : "Close Rick-counters of the Rick Kind", '11' : "Ricksy Business"}

i = 0
root = os.getcwd()
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        for name in names:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, 'Episode {} {}.mkv').format(i, name))

    i += 1
```

Hello, I am new to python program and am trying to rename the files in the folder by adding on the episode name which can be found in the dictionary I made. I need help iterating over it and placing those values in the `name` variable I created.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the episode name (which I assume is the filename) to access the dictionary.

Since you want to look up the episode name using the name (not number), you should flip your dictionary keys and values:

`names = {'1' : 'Pilot', '2' : 'Lawnmower Dog', ...` becomes `names = {'Pilot': '1', 'Lawnmower Dog': '2', ...`

Rather than `for name in names:` try:

```
try:
    name = names[filename]
except KeyError:
    # Filename was not found. Skip
    print("Filename "+filename+" not found")
    continue
```

This may not word depending on how your filename is formatted. I can't tell this from your question currently.

Also `if filename.startswith('E'):` looks like it shouldn't be there.

Comment: When I use your method, I get a .DS_store key error. My videos are formatted like "Episode 1.mkv"

Comment: I used that, and it said it cannot find the files. Yet the directory is correct and the files are there....I checked using the os.getcwd() and I am in the correct directory....

Comment: @JulianL, sorry your dictionary is the other way. Since you are looking up using the episode name (not number) you should flip the `keys` and `values`. Updated the answer